# I can't binding image in document Library from https c# CSOM

Tags: c#, xaml, sharepoint, uwp, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on UWP App with c#.

And i can't binding image from document Library in sharepoint,
I can Retrieve data from list or info of document library by using CSOM, but how to display image?

When i open image's link on browser i have to give username and password before.

So i think that's problem in authentification?

I'm trying to get file and after display it like this,but i don't know how to bind image:

```
using (var context=new ClientContext("https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/demo/"))
    {
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("xxx@xxxx","Pass");
    var file =context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/Demo/mylib/1.jpg");
    context.Load(file);
    await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File File doc = file;
    list.add(new Person(1,"Name","Description", ??Image?? ));
}

**XAML CODE**
<DataTemplate x:Key="ControlCategoryPrincipal" x:DataType="data:Person">
<Ellipse Margin="8,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80"  Width="80">
 <Ellipse.Fill>
  <ImageBrush  Stretch="UniformToFill">
   <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
    <BitmapImage  UriSource="{x:Bind Image}" />
   </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
  </ImageBrush>
 </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
</DataTemplate>
...
<GridView x:Name="gridPrinc"
      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="GroupGridView"
      ItemTemplate ="{StaticResource ControlCategoryPrincipal}"
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind list,Mode=OneWay}"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
      SelectionMode="None"  Loaded="gridPrinc_Loaded">
 </GridView>

**MODEL**
public class Person
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String image;
    private String description;
    ... + GETTERS + SETTERS
    public Person(int id, String n, String desc, String img)
    {
        this.Id = idd;
        this.Name = n;
        this.Image = img;
        this.Description = desc;

    }
}
```

Comment: If you were asked this question, what do you think you'd need in order to solve it?

Comment: question is how to display image by using CSOM ?

Comment: You appear (to me) to be asking a question about code you have that isn't working as expected, but you haven't included the actual code. Thus it is impossible to see what is wrong with said code (if anything)

Comment: please add XAML and model codes more. it's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. list property on the PropertyChanged event did not occur if the output should not
2. list ObservableCollection property Taxes output because this event does not occur unless CollectionChanged
3. x: Bind the OneTime mode is because when data for later binding can be integral

Comment: need example plz, still not working, i can display image if does'nt need authanticate but https from sharepoint can't !!

Comment: Property to get the url in the file is assumed to be "LinkingUrl". The value of the property putting in imageUri is thought to be able to come up the image. Or, the image is then stored in the local storage using the path. http://kaki104.tistory.com/attachment/cfile9.uf@2606974356AE012C0C7C0E.zip sample app code

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/fetching-image-from-sharepoint-2007-picture-library-using-object-model/  you can make MemoryStream from file.OpenBinaryStream(...).. and http://net-informations.com/q/faq/imgtobyte.html MemoryStream to Image converter